# iOS Google storage success object GTLStorageObject Media link always return nil

Tags: objective-c, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading Image data to google storage successfully by using code:

My upload is successfully I can see the uploaded image to google storage.
The Issue is I do not get media link in response. media link is always nil.
Where as all other data in response is present.

- (void)uploadFileToGoogleStorage {

  GTLServiceStorage *serviceStorage = [[GTLServiceStorage alloc] init];

  NSString *accessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [UserDefaultUtils retriveObjectForKey:kAccessToken]];

  serviceStorage.additionalHTTPHeaders = @{@"x-goog-project-id": kGoogleXProjectId, @"Content-Type": @"application/json-rpc", @"Accept": @"application/json-rpc", @"Authorization": accessToken};

  GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch

  ```
                               authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:

                               kKeychainItemName

                               clientID:kMyClientID

                               clientSecret:kMyClientSecret];
  ```

  auth.authorizationTokenKey = @"id_token";

  if([auth canAuthorize]) {

  ```
  serviceStorage.authorizer = auth;
  ```

  }

  NSData  imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_profileImage.image)];

  GTLUploadParameters *uploadParam = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/png"]

  GTLStorageObject *storageObject = [GTLStorageObject object];
  storageObject.name = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
  GTLQueryStorage *query = [GTLQueryStorage queryForObjectsInsertWithObject:
                            storageObject 
                            bucket:kGoogleStorageBucket 
                            uploadParameters:uploadParam];

  GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [serviceStorage executeQuery:query 
                           completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                          id object, NSError *error) {

  ```
                   if (!error) {

                  NSLog(@"Media Link %@",object.mediaLink);

      // Media Link is always nil All other fields in object has data,

  }
  ```

  }];

  ticket.uploadProgressBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead,
                                unsigned long long dataLength) {

  ```
  NSLog(@"Uploading....");
  ```

  };

  }